# Определение пола

Tags: текст

Хочу как в ВК сделать автоматическое определение пола, но не могу понять как это реализовать. Допустим, если ставить женский пол по окончанию имени(а и я), но есть ведь имена: Любовь и другие + есть и мужские имена: Никита, Илья. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что использовать для реализации идеи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще спросить.
Не зря же все сайты спрашивают пол, вместо определения.
Как ни крути, а универсального алгоритма нет.
Можно, конечно, попробовать словарём, исключениями, анализировать сообщения на предмет определения пола автора (последнее, кстати, точно будет работать, но реализовать сложно), но везде есть вероятность ошибки.
Плюс - некоторые вообще муть пишут типа `♥ ღКсюня♥ ღ ღВивенскаяღ` (реальный ник выдрал из ВК), по ней точно ничего  не определишь.

Comment: Нормально все по такому нику определишь, всякая ерунда сразу убирается, остается Ксюня и Вивенская.

Comment: @Lol4t0, Мне лень было искать настоящее уродство, состоящие только из вот этих закорючек. Да и не факт то, что вырвешь из них, будет читаемо. Сколько раз видел ники типа "Ангел мой", "Ганста" (угу, именно так) и прочий бред.

Comment: @Lol4t0 ну вот возьмем хотя бы ваш ник

Comment: @TheDoctor, тут зависит от площадки. Если задача стоит, то как минимум предполагается, что люди регистрируются под именами. А если так, то нечеткий поиск со словрем творят чудеса

Comment: @Lol4t0, Быть может, но зачем такие сложности? Не легче спросить? Если народ там такой правильный и пишет нормальные имена, то он и галочку правильную выберет.

Comment: @TheDoctor, ну, спросить можно только если вы контроллируете площадку, и готовы к тому, чтобы перестролить для этого интерфейс, БД, сделать напоминания существущим пользователям о том, что теперь надо галку поставить.

Comment: @Lol4t0, С начала нужно нормальную архитектуру создавать тогда. А если это только начало, то мы помогли чуваку избавиться от дурной идеи.

Comment: @TheDoctor, вы понимаете, что часто ваше решение просто непрменимо? Если вы проводите какой-нибудь сбор данных, то не моежте просто заставить всех указать свой пол. Пример: составить зависимость мжеду рейтингом и полом пользователей stackoverlow

Comment: @Lol4t0, Можешь не ставить мне обращение, т.к. сообщение моё, мне оповещение придёт автоматом. А мне нужно ставить.
По вопросу - логин у меня может быть как мужским, так и женским. Сообщения от лица мужского пола, ава девушки. Личное имя тоже нельзя однозначно определить, да и оно закрыто для доступа.
Так что как бы не старался - только галочка принесёт профит, кроме сложной нейронной системы анализа сообщений - то, конечно, куда точнее, но и в разы сложнее - оно надо?

Answer (score 5):

Тривиальными средствами вроде проверки окончаний вы эту задачу вряд ли решите по вполне понятным причинам. Возможно, имеет смысл сделать словарь возможных имен - если речь идет о более-менее традиционных русских именах, то это может помочь - как правило в русском языке мужские и женские имена не пересекаются - возможно, я что-то забыл, но я не помню в русском языке ни одного имени, звучащего одинаково для мужчин и для женщин(за исключением уменьшительных форм типа Саша или Женя). 
С другой стороны, это тоже не панацея.

Во-первых, подобный словарь должен быть достаточно большим (причем 95% его содержимого не будет использоваться вообще, либо будет, но редко. Скажем, вряд ли среди ваших пользователей будет много Никандров или Ратиборов)

Во-вторых, если в вашей системе возможны уменьшительные имена, то довольно сложно сказать, является ли условный(ая) Саша мальчиком или девочкой.

В-третьих, с иностранными именами тоже далеко не все гладко - скажем, в английском не редкость, что одно и то же имя может принадлежать мужчине или женщине. А уж если брать восточные имена (китайские например или хотя бы армянские), то там и вовсе черт ногу сломит.

В-четвертых, ничто не мешает пользователю вместо имени ввести вообще что попало, или какой-то ник. Тут в некоторых случаях даже человеческий мозг будет бессилен.

Хотя, с другой стороны, если в вашей системе не предполагается наличие пользователей из Кореи, и в сумеете их убедить писать исключительно имена, а не ники, то с более-менее успешно это может сработать (но все же не стоит забывать что и в этом случае никто ничего не гарантирует)

Можно также попробовать анализировать не тоьлко имя, но и фамилию - женские фамилии часто заканчиваются на "а", но тут никакие словари не помогут - если имена еще как-то можно перечислить, то фамилии могут быть вообще какие угодно. Кроме того, есть куча несклоняемых фамилий типа Дуся Гвоздь или какой-нибудь Петя Иванчук, но все же анализ имени и фамилии одновременно может отсеять некоторые непонятности.

А вот с отчествами все значительно проще - в подавляющем большинстве случаев мужское отчество заканчивается на "вич", а женское на "вна". С другой стороны, отчества может и не быть вовсе, если человек иностранец, либо его не всегда указывают при регистрации.

А мораль этой истории такова: для определения пола используйте галки "М" и "Ж"

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать несколько критериев, например как вы уже сказали по окончанию (на ь мужских имен мало, но есть  - Олесь), плюс еще добавить словарь исключений (типа Никита, Илья). Можно просто словарь (русских имен не так уж много). Если иностранные имена, то тут все сложнее, так как иногда и человек по имени определить пол не сможет, не говоря уж об алгоритме.